# Good endpoints for a RESTful webservice

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I'm building a simple RESTful service, and trying to come up with good design, and intuitive endpoints. These are some of the ideas I came up with after reading a bunch of articles on REST, and wanted to get some feedback.

The resources that will be exposed by the service are books -

```
http://myapp.com/books/?type=fiction&age=15-35&author=american
http://myapp.com/books/35/chapters/2
http://myapp.com/books/35/chapters/2/pages/6
http://myapp.com/books/35/chapters/2/pictures/1
```

Response representation for each endpoint will depend on the method and the Accept header i.e.

GET -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://myapp.com/books/35/chapters/2' should result in
something like

```
{
  "book": "The Adventures Of Huckleberry Finn",
  "title": "The Boys Escape Jim",
  "pages": 15,
  "pictures": 3 
}
```

and the same request with 'Accept: application/xml' would return me an xml representation of the same.

Couple of things that I'm not clear about:

Since REST dictates that we should be using nouns, not verbs, how do i expose an html form to enter new resources?

/new or /add do not RESTful at all.

Would

```
GET 'Accept: text/html' 'http://myapp.com/books/new'
```

be an acceptable way of being an endpoint to a form page? Or perhaps

```
POST 'Accept: text/html' 'http://myapp.com/books/'
```

with an empty body be a better way? And the same POST with an empty body and

```
'Accept: application/json'
```

would end up with http 400 error. Is this a correct/reasonable approach, or is there a better way to do this?

I'm approaching this as a "service that exposes books, chapters, images" resources, and the "web page" is just one of the representations of these resources. So, technically, if I were to put 'Accept: text/html' in any of the mentioned requests, I should expect to get html representation of the requested resource. At the same time html is really not a data describing language, but a presentation language, and following the separation of concerns suggests keeping the model (resources) and the controller (code that processes the requests) separate from the view (html).

In general, should the 'api' that exposes resources be dealt with separately from the UI?
What if it's a small, single page app?

Thank you for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a lot of questions here.  I'll just add my 2 cents.  The Restful API that you show toward the beginning of your post looks good.  Those "nouns" you talked about are the names of your resources, like books, chapters, pages, etc.  The idea of REST revolves around the use of HTTP verbs used to interact with those resources.  GET requests will fetch those resources.  PUT/POST will insert or update those resources and DELETE will remove the resources.

In other words:

GET http://myapp.com/books/35

will get the book with the id of 35, but

POST http://myapp.com/books/

will insert a new book into the backend store using whatever post body you have supplied to represent that book's data.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you. That's basically my though process. The question I'm trying to answer is the one about the endpoints. In order for the POST to add a book, the client needs to know about the necessary fields, etc. For humans that would be done via an html form. So I'm trying to come up with a good RESTful uri to that form. For now I'm inclined in doing http://myapp.com/books/new, where 'new' could be thought of a special book id indicating that a form needs to be presented to the client.

Comment: I think you missed my point.  The url shouldn't change.  It should just be a POST to myapp.com/books with the body containing the book data.  Your server should see a POST coming in and know it needs to create a new book.  Generally the server would then return the saved resource, or just its newly generated id.

Comment: I understand that, but my questions is about what happens before POST with body. POST with body occurs in response to someone filling out and submitting a form (in this example i'm talking about a human interacting with a web app). In order for the form to be submitted, it has to be presented to the user. One way of doing it would be to have a separate page book_form.html (i'm oversimplifying it here), with the form method="POST" action="http://myapp.com/books". Then the client could GET the http://myapp.com/book_form.html, fill it out, and then do the POST.

Comment: Now obviously this is not RESTful at all. I guess, my question could be rephrased as do i need to a have a restful url to the form or since form is not really representing my resource's state it does not matter?

Comment: Your application's front end does not have to conform to REST.  REST stands for Representational State Transfer, specifically transfer of your entities via the Restful Webservice Layer.  Don't even attempt to apply a Restful API to your front end.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again for clarifying it.

Comment: You bet.  If it isn't too much trouble can you pick my answer?